# Execute SQL Server SSIS Package From Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a SSIS package that is stored in a SQL Server 2005 DB.  I am trying to execute  this package from a stored procedure on the same server.   Is there a better way than exec master..xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /SQL...

I am running into (I think) file system permission issues with xp_cmdshell that is preventing execution

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, here are two good articles:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-server-2005/executing-ssis-packages-/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Call_SSIS_from_SP.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using Agent instead:

1. Create Agent proxy account for the account that will run the job
2. Create Agent job that runs this package
3. Make it use the proxy account created in #1
4. Test the job
5. In SQL code, use `sp_start_job` to start this job

The downside is that you can't easily pass the parameters from SQL to the package this way.

Comment: I recently came up with a detailed solution based on this idea for anyone that needs an example through [***this stackoverflow question***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535338/execute-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-as-proxy-user-without-xp-cmdshell)

Answer (score 1):

Since 2012, MSSQL has an SSIS Catalog, where you can park your packages there. You can then execute a package with parameters. This way we can avoid `xp_cmdshell` to call `dtexec`, or `sp_start_job` without parameters. Key SPs: `create_execution`, `set_execution_parameter_value`, and `start_execution`.

From MSDN:

[To run a package on the server using SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231084.aspx)

[Deploy and Execute SSIS Packages using Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)