# How to allow sql athentication to run ssis packages in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssis, etl

I have created an SSIS project with multiple packages, they work well in my development machine and also when deployed to the server of the organization i work for (running them with SQL management studio and a given user within the active directory of the company).

I also have created an asp.net web application to run the packages, which runs without issues the packages with the following ConnectionStrings:

```
<add name="DBQueries" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=SSISDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But as soon as i set SQL Server authentication and change the ConnectionStrings to the next one it just doesn't work:

```
<add name="DBQueries" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=SSISDB;user=user;password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The company won't let the application to have the ConnectionString with Integrated Security. Its there a workaround or anything i can do in the configuration of the SQL user or the SSIS packages?

**EDIT:** Debugging i found this:

```
The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Integrated Authentication.
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions associated with the user/pass you're using in the second connection string?

Comment: "Just doesn't work" doesn't mean anything. Please do some digging and find an error message in a log somewhere that gives you a clue. i.e. Does that package log indiacate that it started? Do the IIS logs indicate it tried to start?

Comment: Nick, this is the error that i get: "The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Integrated Authentication."

Comment: which log was that and what operation is it referring to?

Answer (score 2):

SSIS jobs when they are executed from catalog impersonate caller context for all calls inside and outside of SQL Server. So package will not be executed if SSIS can't impersonate windows context of the caller.
Bottom line is that you need to start package from a windows authenticated session.

There are multiple solutions, I would say simplest one is to use SQL Agent, i.e. create SQL Agent job run under Window proxy account and then ASP.Net app will start this Agent job.

Comment: You're right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189480/executing-ssis-package-with-sql-authentication