# Azure devops - SSIS Deploy

Tags: deployment, ssis, azure-devops

Following is the error am getting when using "SSIS Deploy" plugin in my Release Job.

Azure Devops Release - Deploy SSIS (Tried using SQL Authentication failed & using ActiveDirectory Password, it is connecting but it is failing to establish the connection with the SSISDB database). When i connect using Windows Authentication
[image]

Error: Funny thing is i can connect SSISDB from my SSMS without issues using my **sa** account.
However using **Azure Devops - SSIS Deploy plugin** I cannot deploy the SSIS packages using **sa** account. Crazy!
[image]

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a specific authentication type is supported depends on destination server type and agent type. Detail support matrix is listed in below table. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#authentication-type) .

[image]

In addition, here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850142/11508192) with similar issue you can refer to.