# Integration Services Catalog - Accessing a network drive

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have deployed a SSIS Package to the Integration Services Catalogs.  The issue that I am having is that the flat file source does not have access to the network drive.

How do I configure the package to run under another account.

The reason I chose this route is I wanted to be able to run the SSIS package from a WebAPI and just running a stored procedure.

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'Domain\User'
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'CDMS', @project_name=N'Package Import', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id <----Fails
```

**Update:**
I tried 2 scenarios in SQL Management studio:

1. When logged in as a SQL Account: The current security context cannot be reverted. Please switch to the original database where 'Execute As' was called and try it again. ( Btw I am not even calling REVERT)
2. Logged in as Windows Auth and removed the Login statement: Cannot open the datafile...

Question in scenario 2, It is clear SQL is not accessing the network drive under my account.  But when using EXECUTE as LOGIN..Does that then access the network drive under the login specified?

**UPDATE 2**
I have changed the permissions of the share to Modified for Everyone and I am still getting this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute SSIS package from stored procedure as proxy user without xp\_cmdshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535338/execute-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-as-proxy-user-without-xp-cmdshell)

Comment: The web page will call a stored procedure which then runs an SSIS package from the SSISDB. What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: @billinkc  SQL Server 2016

Comment: @billinkc if the package is executed via a proc, does this run under the context of the database engine service account?  If so, all that would need to be done is grant that account permissions to the file system

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I tried running under windows authentication which did have access, but that didnt work., So I would say it the service account

Comment: I would try granting access to the database engine service account and see if that works - if it doesn't try the integration services service account.